# How to find the biggest sum of a square in a matrix using python

Tags: python, function, matrix

I am trying to write a code that will give me the biggest sum of a square in a matrix.

note: the values have to be next to each other while forming the shape of a square.

note 2: I am only allowed to use functions, importing anything isn't allowed currently in the class I am taking.

For example:

```
 max_mat_square([[1,2.5,3],
                 [4,-4,6],
                 [0.5,-1,5]])

[7.5]
```

Now this is the code I have:

```
def max_mat_square(mat):
    sum1 = []
    for i in range(len(mat[:-1])):
        print i
        for j in range(len(mat[1:])):
                print 'index' , j
                sum1.append([float(mat[i][j]) + float(mat[i+1][j])+float(mat[i][j+1])+float(mat[i+1][j+1])])
    return max(sum1)
```

Now the code works fine with the first example, However whenever I run this matrix throw it:

```
max_mat_square([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
```

I get 'list index out of range' error,
The result I want for this matrix is 18.

I tried a lot of methods to fix the error, but none of them worked.

Comment: with "square" you mean the highest 2x2 area inside your matrix summed together?

Comment: yes! it has to be 2x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first example works only co-incidentally because of the shape of your matrix. Currently the slicing used in that loop means you are selecting from the second sub-list to the end:

```
mat[1:]
>> [[3,4], [5,6]]
```

Which implies you'll try to loop through each element with `range(2)` which will go out of range.

Change the second for statement as follows:

```
def max_mat_square(mat):
    sum1 = []
    for i in range(len(mat[:-1])):
        for j in range(len(mat[i])-1):
            print (i , j)
            sum1.append([float(mat[i][j]) + float(mat[i+1][j])+float(mat[i][j+1])+float(mat[i+1][j+1])])
    return max(sum1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your inner `for` loop. You should have `j` starting from 0 up to the *row's* second last index:

```
for j in range(len(mat[i][:-1])):
    ...
```

So your final function becomes:

```
def max_mat_square(mat):
    sum1 = []
    for i in range(len(mat[:-1])):
        print(i)
        for j in range(len(mat[i][:-1])):
                print('index' , j)
                sum1.append([float(mat[i][j]) + float(mat[i+1][j])+float(mat[i][j+1])+float(mat[i+1][j+1])])
    return max(sum1)
```